# Setting cookies in Volley

Tags: java, android, http, cookies, android-volley

I have and app that receives authentication token and needs to use it as a key,
but when I add the cookie this way:...

```
@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            if(getCookie() != null){
                String cookie = getCookie();

                headers.put("Set-Cookie", cookie);
            }
            return headers;
        }
```

... it doesn't work. The String "cookie" is in correct format (PHPSESSID=e52e3536ca97710d68b8980f22ea24b9), so the problem is elsewhere.

Is this the right way to add cookies in Volley?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the solution was simple: I just renamed "Set-Cookie" to "Cookie" and it works.